# Why does this switch statement fail?

Tags: javascript

```
switch (t.value) {
    case < 5:
        alert('hi');
        break;
}
```

I know it's the part where I have "< 5". How do I make it so that it has a case where t.value is less than 5??

Comment: Why can't you just use a plain old if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` statement seems best suited for this purpose, but *although I do not recommend it* the fact that JavaScript will let you switch on any datatype (and not just numbers/enums like some languages) means you can do this:

```
switch(true) {
   case t.value < 5:
      // do something
      break;
   case t.value >= 112:
      // do something
      break;
   case someOtherVar == 17:
      // do something
      break;
   case x == 7:
   case y == "something":
   case z == -12:
   case a == b * c:
      // works with fallthrough
      break;
   case someFunc():
      // even works on a function call (someFunc() should return true/false)
      break;
   default:
      // whatever
      break;
}
```

The above should select whichever case matches first, noting that several if not all of the cases could be true.

In a way that style is more readable than a long series of `if/else if`, but I wouldn't use it in a team development environment where it could confuse other developers.

Another, more conventional use of `switch` for your less than 5 scenario would be as follows (assuming you know the range that `t.value` could possibly be):

```
switch(t.value) {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
      // do something
      break;
   case 5:
   // etc
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to prefer this over a chain of `if ... else if`, especially since you have to remember to `break;` in between each case.

Comment: Well I did say I don't recommend it. I certainly don't prefer it. In practice I've never done it except for learning purposes. But I don't hate it.

Answer (score 4):

switch only supports equality comparisons.

```
if (t.value < 5) {
    alert('hi');
}
```

I don't know if it fits your particular case, but you could also do something like this:

```
switch (t.value) {
    case 5:
    case 4:
    case 3:
    case 2:
    case 1:
        alert('hi');
        break;
}
```

Comment: If you switch on a boolean you can 'cheat' and use all of the sorts of comparison expressions you would use in an `if/else if` structure. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements don't support less-than or greater-than comparisons (or anything other than *equals*). Use:

```
if (t.value < 5) {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: Actually `switch` does support less-than or other boolean-result expressions (even with function calls) if you 'cheat' and switch on a boolean. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

default:
  if(t.value< 5)
   alert('hi');
  break;
Maybe it's you want!